# Не отображается AdView. Какие версии каких библиотек подключить к проекту?

Tags: android, admob

Разметка рекламного блока:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/setTimer" >
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Подключена библиотека play_services_ads 11.6.0. Визуальный редактор выдаёт следующее:

```
    The following classes could not be instantiated:
    - com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
    See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.


    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/android/gms/R$styleable

        at com.google.android.gms.internal.bb.<init>(    
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.bh.<init>(    at com.google.android.gms.internal.bh.<init>(    at com.google.android.gms.internal.bh.<init>(    at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.<init>(    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:444)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:196)
        at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:206)
        at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:131)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:718)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:372)
```

В логах, естественно, ошибка по строке:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

Какие версии каких библиотек подключить к проекту?

IDE Eclipse Mars, версия SDK 25.2.5, SDK Build Tools 19.1.

Comment: Вообще, если делать на рекомендуемой IDE (Android Studio) и рекомендуемой системе сборки `gradle` то, скорее всего, проблема решилась бы строкой `apply plugin 'google-play-services'`. А в случае неподдерживаемых IDE и устаревших версий либ попробуйте тут почитать `https://stackoverflow.com/a/42981792/3212712`

Comment: Прочитал, сделал. Те же самые ошибки. Использовать AdMobAds SDK?

Comment: К сожалению более ничего предложить не могу(

Comment: Используйте [документацию от google](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) .  Не забудьте добавить `google-services.json`. Как его добавить можете прочитать в последнем пункте [этой статьи](https://habrahabr.ru/post/316528/).

Comment: Это всё для Android Studio. У меня же Eclipse, и переход на AS займёт время на пересборку конфигурации рабочего пространства и самого проекта. А это куча времени и потерянные остальные эклипсовские проекты. Подключал GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.3.0.jar, но, оказывается, ниже 7.0.0 поддерживать не будут. А с Play Services возникает обозначенная проблема.